# Set one array values as keys in new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
[
  {date:'27-06-2021',name:'John Doe',count:2},
  {date:'29-06-2021',name:'John Doe',count:1},
  {date:'29-06-2021',name:'George Newman',count:1},
]
```

I would like to change or transform that array into a new one where the name values are the keys and the counts are those key's values plus sum them up by date.

wanted outcome:

```
[
  {date:'27-06-2021',John Doe:2,sumCount:2},
  {date:'29-06-2021',John Doe:1,George Newman:1,sumCount:2},
]
```

Is there any possible way to get that outcome ?

Thanks ,

Comment: FYI: You need to use quotes if your key contains spaces.

Comment: Yeah I know thanks :) @Terry

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea to create so many different objects? Wouldn't it be smarter to create an object containing an array of persons instead of one attribute for each person?

Comment: Honestly I did not think about it , I'm rewriting an old app and the outcome is an array mapped inside a table so i'm trying to copy that

Comment: Your desired data structure contains redundant data. Like what @ClausBönnhoff suggested, it might make sense to store the people as an array of objects per date entry. And with that, `sumCount` is no longer needed since you can easily sum up the count when necessary.

Comment: I will try that @Terry

Comment: It is straightforward to do this with [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), but how are you going to consume the result? Use `Object.entries` and remove the date and sumCount to get the names? That's unwieldy, and what would be the point of even having the count in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some simple logic to group the array.

```js
const input = [
  { date: '27-06-2021', name: 'John Doe', count: 2 },
  { date: '29-06-2021', name: 'John Doe', count: 1 },
  { date: '29-06-2021', name: 'George Newman', count: 1 },
]

const output = [];
input.forEach((record) => {
  searchNode = output.find((node) => node.date === record.date);
  if(searchNode) {
    searchNode.sumCount += 1;
    if (searchNode[record.name]) {
      searchNode[record.name] += 1
    } else {
      searchNode[record.name] = 1
    }
  }
  else {
    pushNode = {
      date: record.date,
      sumCount: record.count,
    };
    pushNode[record.name] = 1;
    output.push(pushNode);
  }
})
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `Array.prototype.reduce` to collect the dates into a dictionary using the dates as the unique key, and then using `Object.values()` to retrieve the values of the dictionary.

```
const transformedData = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    // We can unpack these in the argument, but I moved them here for clarity
    const { date, name, count } = cur;

    // Construct dictionary using `date` as the key
    if (date in acc) {
        acc[date].sumCount += count;
    } else {
        acc[date] = {
            date,
            sumCount: count
        };
    }

    // We use name as keys to keep track of individual count
    // If name is nullish, then we start with 0
    acc[date][name] = (acc[date][name] ?? 0) + count;

    return acc;
}, {}));
```

Proof-of-concept example:

```js
const data = [{
    date: '27-06-2021',
    name: 'John Doe',
    count: 2
  },
  {
    date: '29-06-2021',
    name: 'John Doe',
    count: 1
  },
  {
    date: '29-06-2021',
    name: 'George Newman',
    count: 1
  },
];

const transformedData = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, { date, name, count }) => {
  if (date in acc) {
    acc[date].sumCount += count;
  } else {
    acc[date] = {
      date,
      sumCount: count
    };
  }
  
  acc[date][name] = (acc[date][name] ?? 0) + count;
  
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(transformedData);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let data = [
  {date:'27-06-2021',name:'John Doe',count:2},
  {date:'29-06-2021',name:'John Doe',count:1},
  {date:'29-06-2021',name:'George Newman',count:1},
];

data = data.map(function(obj)
{
  obj[obj['name']] = obj['count'];
  delete obj['name'];
  delete obj['count'];
  
  return obj;
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: "*plus sum them up by date*" - an explanation would also be helpful...